# How to get uniqueDeviceID in Ionic 3 without need for a special permission like "Allow to make and manage phone calls"?

Tags: ionic3, angular5

I am using the code provided in the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/unique-device-id/) to get a unique identifier for the device:

```
getDeviceUniqueId() {
this.uniqueDeviceID.get()
.then((uuid: string) => this.uniqueDeviceIdStr = uuid)
.catch((error: any) => {
this.uniqueDeviceIdStr = “N/A”;
this.loggingService.logError(“Error getting device unique identifier”, error);
});
}
```

However, when this code is executed the following message is displayed:

“Allow to make and manage phone calls?”

I am testing against an Android device (version 7) and my application does not require this permission for any other functionality. Removing the code also removes this permission requirement dialog.

The unique identifier is properly displayed if I grant the app the requested permission.

Question: How to get UniqueDeviceID in Ionic 3 without need for a special permission? i need this UniqueDeviceID for pushing notifications, **and not uuid which provided in [device](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device/) library**.

Comment: you can use device plugin also for getting the uuid and it doesnt require any special permission